# Fill a table horiziantally

Tags: python, html

say i have a list

```
e.g.

apple
car
bin
```

How to i get it to fill horizonatlly in a table rather than vertically i.e so it looks like this in a table:

```
apple car bin
```

The code im using just repeats each entry of the list for the entire row, code below:

```
<body> 
    <div metal:fill-slot="main">
        <h1>List of Species in the Database</h1>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
            <tr tal:repeat="records container/Query_Species">
                <td tal:content="records/gene_bank_species">Species</td>
                <td tal:content="records/gene_bank_species">Species</td>            
            </tr>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr tal:repeat="records container/Query_Species">
        <td tal:content="records/gene_bank_species">Species</td>
    </tr>
    <tr tal:repeat="records container/Query_Species">
        <td tal:content="records/gene_bank_species">Species</td>            
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: The list gets repated twice, in a column

Comment: You should replace the first "Species" by "apple" and the secound one by "car". I think then you'll get the point